# onViewStateRestored crashing android app

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Android development. I wanted to save user login data so that he doesnt have to login after pausing and resuming the app or when he uses the app again. After going through some posts on stackoverflow, I realised onSavedInstance is the way to do it.

I have implemented the methods in one loginActivity but the app gives an error when i open this activity on the emulator.
the error is **Unfortunately, 'Project_name' has stopped**

So, I checked the log files, and got this

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**

on the line

boolean inSession = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("loggedin");

in the onViewStateRestored method.

Can someone help me find out where am i going wrong and Is there any better way to store login details so that user doesn't have to log in everytime the app goes in pause or stop mode?

Thanks for the help in advance. :)

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if(inSession){
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("loggedin",true);
        savedInstanceState.putString("email",emailcol);
        savedInstanceState.putString("password",passwordcol);
        savedInstanceState.putString("type","login");
    }
    else{
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("loggedin",false);

    }
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);

        boolean inSession = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("loggedin");
        if (inSession) {
            String email = savedInstanceState.getString("email");
            String pass = savedInstanceState.getString("password");
            String type = "login";
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker(this.getContext());
            //(Name,password,email,contact,address,type
            bw.execute(null, pass, email, null, null, type);
        }

}
```

Comment: try moving the statement `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);` to end of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState)When your activity is recreated after it was previously destroyed, you can recover your saved state from the Bundle that the system passes your activity. Both the onCreate() and onRestoreInstanceState() callback methods receive the same Bundle that contains the instance state information.

Because the onCreate() method is called whether the system is creating a new instance of your activity or recreating a previous one, you must check whether the state Bundle is null before you attempt to read it. If it is null, then the system is creating a new instance of the activity, instead of restoring a previous one that was destroyed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

// Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // Restore value of members from saved state
    mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
    mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
} else {
    // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
}
...
```

}

You should probably use [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store user login info

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Before getBoolean check its null or not

```
if (savedInstanceState!= null) { //check its not null

boolean inSession = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("loggedin");
    if (inSession) {
        String email = savedInstanceState.getString("email");
        String pass = savedInstanceState.getString("password");
        String type = "login";
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker(this.getContext());
        //(Name,password,email,contact,address,type
        bw.execute(null, pass, email, null, null, type);
    }


}
```

Comment: But, After the user logs in now, and then goes onpause and comes back, he is logged out

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate function, this Bundle is handed back to the program. The best way to check if the application is being reloaded, or started for the first time is:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
// Then the application is being reloaded
}
```